# Debian 9: Cannot install SDL2-dev or SFML-dev

Tags: debian, package-management

I have been trying to install the development packages of SFML and SDL2 on Debian 9 but have been unable. I cannot copy paste my log because my Debian is not english.

- Both packages complain that `libgl1-mesa-dev` cannot be installed.
- Trying to install `libgl1-mesa-dev` will yield a complaint that
  `mesa-common-dev` cannot be installed.
- Trying to install that one yields a complaint about
  `libdrm-dev`

Now I think the root of the problem lies with `libdrm2`, the version installed on my machine is `2.4.95-1~bpo9+1` but all those packages expect version `2.4.74-1`.

The problem is that I cannot downgrade without uninstalling about 151 packages, most of them vital.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have parts of Mesa installed from backports, you need to install the rest from there too:

```
sudo apt -t stretch-backports libsdl2-dev libsfml-dev
```

SDL2 and SFML aren’t in backports, but this will instruct `apt` to use backports for other dependencies.